# Error code: 2195 IBM MQ

Tags: c#, message-queue, ibm-mq, mq

I am using below code to connect IBM MQ...

```
public static void CreateConnectionWithBARXMQ()
        {
            XMSFactoryFactory factoryFactory;
            IConnectionFactory cf = null;

            factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
            cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, <some-host-name>);
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 1422);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, <some-channel>);
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, <some-manager>);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_NAME, <some-queue>);

            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QMGR_CCSID, XMSC.CCSID_UTF8);

            IConnection connection = cf.CreateConnection();
        }
```

This code is working fine with unsecured MQ channel. but when I change channel from unsecured to secured one and and security exit code as mentioned below...

```
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SECURITY_EXIT, @"C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\exits\BCPKIJCExit_70R.dll");
```

it is throwing very generic error...

```
CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2195
. During execution of the specified method an exception was thrown by another component. See the linked exception for more information.
```

I checked the linked exception but it has same error message as above.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here.

Comment: I would expect an FDC to be cut to go with an MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR - do you have any FDC files?

Comment: I am not sure what FDC is?

Comment: It's a First Failure Data Capture, like a dump file of sorts. Look in your error directory for files with the extension *.FDC

Comment: How did you get the LinkedException property?  I mean, "what type of exception" class are you using to cast the Exception class object?

Answer (score 1):

The `2195 return code` is a *high-level exception* that is hit when errors are not caught at lower levels in the code. Very often these are generated when some external dependency such as **file access** or **Os resources** *does not* behave as expected and the failure cascades into `WMQ`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to answer a bunch of questions:

- What is 'BCPKIJCExit_70R.dll'?
- Is it designed for IBM MQ?
- Is the DLL an MQ client-side security exit?
- Is it a native DLL or a .NET DLL?

Comment: BCPKIJCExit_70R.dll is used to connect with secure channel in MQ. it is designed by IBM and comes with websphere MQ package. it is native DLL.

Comment: I'm not sure it does come with MQ. Where did you find it in the MQ install directory?

Comment: Yes...I found it in MQ installation directory

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need some **certificates to use secured XMS** communication.
I had the same error (2195), when I tried to establish a secure XMS communication with *wrong* ssl certificates.
As user01928374655647382910019283 said the error is totally unspecific I was just lucky to have the idea recreating the certificates!

The error that occurs on *missing* ssl certificates is more clear like ".. ssl repository not found ..."

In my client **(v MQ 7.5)** I had to specify them as follows

My example code looks like

```
        ...
        // Get an instance of factory.
        factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);

        // Create WMQ Connection Factory.
        cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

        // Set the properties
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, CoreMqConfiguration.Hostname);
        cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, CoreMqConfiguration.Port);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, CoreMqConfiguration.Channel);
        cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, CoreMqConfiguration.QueueManagerName);
        // for secure communication with SSL            
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, CoreMqConfiguration.CipherSpec);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, "<path\to\ssl>\key");

        // Create connection.
        connectionWMQ = cf.CreateConnection();
        ...
```

while **cipher spec** in my case is

"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"

To create the appopriate key repository I was using the tool

**%Program Files (x86)%\IBM\Websphere MQ\bin\strmqikm.exe.**

In addition you may have a look
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247129/setting-up-net-ibm-xms-client-with-ssl):

I guess it won't resolve your problem at once but I hope it helps to set up a working and secured XMS client

Answer (score 0):

com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2195'.

The error because of DB password getting expire in next six days. We reset the DB password and issue is resolve.

Comment: They are not asking about java.